# External javascript that contains jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have been asked to include an external js file into a site where I don't have direct access to modify it and the generated script has jQuery it that references $.

Is it possible to include this without modifying the source js file?

I've added it as below

```
drupal_add_js("www.domain.com/my.js", array(
      'type' => 'external',
      'scope' => 'header',
      'group' => JS_LIBRARY,
      'every_page' => TRUE,
      'weight' => -1,
    ));
```

But I get undefined errors due to the use of $

Cheers

Comment: Sure, add `$ = jQuery` somewhere before that script loads; but bear in mind you'll break jQuery no conflict, whether that causes problems depends on what other JS your site needs. This is really more of a JS question rather than a Drupal one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to circumvent this would be by installing the [jQuery Dollar](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_dollar) module.

This would allow you to avoid $ conflicts.